# Angular Nodejs MySql CORS issue

Tags: node.js, cors

This is the way I have CORS enabled on nodejs. But the request from the frontend to update records doesn't seem to be working. But get,post,delete commands work.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {//Middleware for CORS. Code to allow requests from any url
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept ");
next();
```

})

This is the way I am executing the update statement on Nodejs

```
backend.put('/updateworkorder/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let sql = "UPDATE workorders SET ? WHERE ?"
    db.query(sql, [{accountNumber: req.body.accountNumber,
        customerName: req.body.customerName,
        packageName: req.body.packageName,
        addons: req.body.addons,
        campaignName: req.body.campaignName,
        notes: req.body.notes,
        entryDate: new Date(req.body.entryDate),
        crew: req.body.crew,
        postDate: new Date(req.body.postDate),
        status: req.body.status
    }, 
        {id: req.body.id}], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Here is the calling part which is in Angular

```
 updateWorkOrder(workOrder) {
    // console.log(workOrder.id);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
    return this.http.put(this.BASE_URL + '/updateworkorder/' + workOrder.id, {headers: headers});
  }
```

This is the error on chromes console
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your method mapping, your URL should contain ID to be recognized by mapping template. Server can't recognize URL template and returns 404.
To make valid URL and pass data to request you should change your method on UI to

```
this.http.put<IWorkOrders>(this.BASE_URL + '/updateworkorder/' + workOrder.id, workOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ID in your the URL your are PUTing to, which is why you are getting a 404 Not Found error. In the logs you can see the URL you are calling is '/backend/updateworkorder/', when it should be '/backend/updateworkorder/your-id'.

Update your call to:

```
this.http.put<IWorkOrders>(this.BASE_URL + '/updateworkorder/' + workOrder.id);
```

Comment: I changed , still the same. I think the issue is with nodejs part. the console.log(req.body) doesn't show any details of that record passed in from the frontend.

Comment: Can you post another screenshot of the request in Chrome? Are you still getting a 404 Not Found?

Comment: I have update http call part from the frontend with the headers. No when i execute it it nulls out each and every column of that record in mysql.

Comment: I feel like I am in the right direction, just something silly is happening somewhere.